# WebStorm AngularJS, Angular CLI, React Native & React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, webstorm, client-side

I couldn't find an answer to this... so, when I open a new project in WebStorm I have the 4 options (and many more) mentioned above - AngularJS, Angular CLI, React Native & React App. I have found out that Angular CLI is corresponding to Angular 2.

**My question is:** which of the 4 or maybe another option I did not mention here is corresponding to Angular 4 which is the newer version of Angular 2 as I understand it.

Also, if someone can please help me understand better the difference between the 4 options I have mentioned: which should I use and for what purpose? For example if I want to build a minesweeper game, which of the three would you choose?

Also, in my search I've found that React Native is for mobile use (apps) so what is the difference between that and React App? And is any of these are suitable for creating a game in PC browser (and not on mobile)?

Comment: First of all there is no Angular2 or Angular4, it is just called Angular because of the semantic versioning (SEMVER).

That's all I will answer... too many questions. StackOverflow is not here to do your research.

Comment: thanks for answering... and I have done a long research and couldn't find the answers...that is why i posted the questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.'Angular CLI' option allows creating Angular 4 project using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)

2. 'AngularJS' option just clones https://github.com/angular/angular-seed - a project stub for [Angular 1](https://angularjs.org/) application
3. 'React Native' creates a React Native project stub using [react native cli](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#the-react-native-cli)
4. 'React App' creates a React project stub with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

**React** itself is a JavaScript library; **React Native** allows creating mobile applications using **React** library + native components. If you like to create a web game to be run in browser, you don't need react Native. You can use React, or Angular.x, or any other JavaScript framework that supports creating custom UI components